# What is it called when two senses of the same word are etymologically independent?

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology

Sometimes different senses of the same word have different etymons. For example,  **mole**  as a small burrowing animal and **mole** as a chemical quantity are etymologically unrelated.

Is there a name for this situation?

Comment: They are just homonyms.  Like "bark" or "rose".

Comment: Curiously, *mole* as in Avogadro’s number is etymologically related to *mole* as in a stone breakwater, both coming from Latin *moles* by different routes

Comment: @HotLicks "bottle" as a verb and "bottle" as a noun are homonyms but share an etymon.

Comment: @kdog - Yep, there's no term for homonyms that do not have a common etymology.

Comment: @HotLicks, no, there is, wikipedia calls these *true homonyms* right in the lede for [[homonym]]. The definition is still difficult, because there are various degrees of relation. It's even more difficult if rejecting the idea of genetic language relation, which while claiming to serve rigor is not actually rigorously definable without circular reasoning and dancing around the issue at an arbitrarily set save distance. It's trivial in many cases though, regardless of the odd edge case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe ***[homograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homograph)*** is what you're looking for.

> #### Homograph:
>
> *Homographs are words that are spelled alike, but have different meanings and sometimes different pronunciations*. The root graph comes from the Greek word meaning “drawn or written,” thus these terms are written the same. For example, stalk is both a plant stem and a verb meaning to pursue stealthily. ***Homographs also have different etymologies***.
>
> Homonyms are words spelled or pronounced alike but different in meaning. *Since homonym is used to (ambiguously) describe either a homograph or homophone, it can cause confusion*, though it is often heard in classrooms in early grades. The root -nym simply means “word” or “name,” so it applies more broadly than its counterparts.

[[Dictionary.com]](https://www.dictionary.com/e/homograph-vs-homophone-vs-homonym/)

Comment: A homonym has both the same spelling and the same pronunciation.

Comment: @HotLicks, Yes....?? *"Homonyms are words spelled or pronounced alike but different in meaning."*

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Great answer thank you. Unfortunately, although the OED limits the term "homograph" to senses of different origin, other sources, notably Wikipedia's list of homographs, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_homographs allow homographs to have the same origin. This makes actually using the term usefully impossible, since there are two entirely inconsistent definitions in wide use.

Comment: DecapitatedSoul, @HotLicks is claiming that homonyms must have both the same spelling and pronunciation simultaneously, whereas your source states that one, the other, or both being alike is sufficient for homonymy.